# File output stops after outputting 8192 characters

Tags: c++, file-io, console

I'm just trying out some file handling stuff.
I have an array with max size of about 100 000 characters, and I've got it to fill up to about 11000 characters.

I attempted on outputting the array back on a file.
But I've realized the file was cut off at an odd place.
So I looked into the actual array, and realized that the file output only got to its 8192nd character. (str[8191])

```
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, Encrypt &s) {
    if(s.c_count == 0) { 
        cerr << "No ciphertext available!" << endl; os << "";
    }
    else 
        for(int i=0; i<s.c_count; i++) { 
            os << s.txt.m[i]; 
    }

    return os;
}
```

This is my operator function for my class Encrypt.

```
OutputName = "OUT.txt";
fstream ofile(OutputName.c_str(), ios_base::app);
ofile << encrypt;
```

My 8193rd character is just a normal character, it's not like a null character or anything.  Why is this happening and how can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

+) When I do the exact same thing, and do

```
cout << encrypt;
```

instead of,

```
ofile << encrypt;
```

it works completely fine.

Comment: Give us some piece of problematic code

Comment: @undercover My code right now is quite long, and I wasn't sure which bits of the code will be needed.

Comment: Maybe let's start with file writing fragment

Comment: Did you close your filestream?

Comment: @undercover I've uploaded some bits of my code. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: @AlvinArulselvan At the end of program, yes.

Comment: @Haxify close it before your return statement and see if that works

Comment: @AlvinArulselvan Can I close the fstream from other cpp file? I opened fstream on main function, and my operator function is on another cpp file.

Comment: @AlvinArulselvan Closing the fstream right after ofile << encrypt; statement worked, thanks! May I ask how this works?

Comment: @Haxify I think it should also work when you would flush() stream instead of closing it right after. close() forces writing any pending data from stream to file.

Comment: flush() writes the content of the buffer to the destination and makes the buffer empty for further data to store and does not close the stream. That means you can still write some more data to the stream.

But close() closes the stream permanently. If you want to write further amounts of data, you must reopen the stream again and append the data

Comment: So flush() would be better solution for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to close the stream permanently.You must reopen the stream again and append the data:

```
OutputName = "OUT.txt";
fstream ofile(OutputName.c_str(), ios_base::app);
Outputname.close();
ofile << encrypt;
```

Or this if you wanna make the buffer empty to store data further and **NOT** close the stream:

```
OutputName = "OUT.txt";
fstream ofile(OutputName.c_str(), ios_base::app);
Outputname.flush();
ofile << encrypt;
```

I am not a C++ programmer,but I assume that all streams have a character limit of 8192 bytes.For performance reasons it makes sense to use a multiple of 512 bytes when writing a file and 8kb seemed reasonable enough.