# How can I get the full string contained within a std::stringstream, when stringstream.str() has a mysterious limit of 8192 characters?

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm using https://github.com/biaks/prometheus-cpp-lite/ in a ESP32 project (i.e. I am a C++ noob).

I'm fetching the metrics into a `std::stringstream`:

```cpp
std::stringstream bodyStream;
prometheus::TextSerializer::Serialize(bodyStream, metrics::Registry.Collect());

// get the string
const std::string bodyString = bodyStream.str();
const char *bodyChars = bodyString.c_str();

// debug printing
Serial.print("bodyString.length(): ");
Serial.println(bodyString.length()); // prints at most 8192
Serial.println(bodyChars); // prints at most 8192 characters
```

However this never prints the full string - it's always limited to a maximum of 8192 characters. This means that the metrics can never be scraped because they're always cut halfway through a metric, so Prometheus fails to parse them.

Why is the string limited to a length of 8192? How can I get the full string?

The documentation for `stringstream.str()` and `bodyStream.rdbuf()->str()` is rather unhelpful:

```cpp
/**
 *  @brief  Copying out the string buffer.
 *  @return  A copy of one of the underlying sequences.
 *
 *  <em>If the buffer is only created in input mode, the underlying
 *  character sequence is equal to the input sequence; otherwise, it
 *  is equal to the output sequence.</em> [27.7.1.2]/1
 */
```

I've no idea what this documentation is supposed to mean...

---

I have tried constructing the `std::stringstream` and providing a pre-sized larger string to use as its buffer:

```cpp
std::string bufStr (10000, 'x');
std::stringstream bodyStream(bufStr);
prometheus::TextSerializer::Serialize(bodyStream, metrics::Registry.Collect());
```

However, this triggers an error (which I can't decipher)

```
abort() was called at PC 0x4015f537 on core 1

Backtrace: 0x400838fd:0x3ffdb900 0x4008d40d:0x3ffdb920 0x40092e5d:0x3ffdb940 0x4015f537:0x3ffdb9c0 0x4015f57e:0x3ffdb9e0 0x4015f531:0x3ffdba00 0x400d97a7:0x3ffdba20 0x400da826:0x3ffdba60 0x400d35cd:0x3ffdbbb0 0x400dc5cd:0x3ffdbc00 0x400de6fd:0x3ffdc180 0x400f18af:0x3ffdc1a0 0x400f18ea:0x3ffdc1d0 0x400eef99:0x3ffdc220 0x400ef059:0x3ffdc270 0x400ef311:0x3ffdc2d0 0x400ead27:0x3ffdc2f0 0x400ead76:0x3ffdc320 0x400eadb9:0x3ffdc340 0x400eaf01:0x3ffdc360 0x400eaf86:0x3ffdc380

  #0  0x400838fd:0x3ffdb900 in panic_abort at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_system/panic.c:408
  #1  0x4008d40d:0x3ffdb920 in esp_system_abort at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_system/esp_system.c:137
  #2  0x40092e5d:0x3ffdb940 in abort at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/newlib/abort.c:46
  #3  0x4015f537:0x3ffdb9c0 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-x86_64-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:47
  #4  0x4015f57e:0x3ffdb9e0 in std::terminate() at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-x86_64-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:57
  #5  0x4015f531:0x3ffdba00 in __cxa_rethrow at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-x86_64-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:133
  #6  0x400d97a7:0x3ffdba20 in prometheus::ClientMetric* std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, prometheus::ClientMetric*>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, prometheus::ClientMetric*) at d:\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/stl_uninitialized.h:89
      (inlined by) prometheus::ClientMetric* std::uninitialized_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, prometheus::ClientMetric*>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, prometheus::ClientMetric*) at d:\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134
      (inlined by) prometheus::ClientMetric* std::__uninitialized_copy_a<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, prometheus::ClientMetric*, prometheus::ClientMetric>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<prometheus::ClientMetric const*, std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > >, prometheus::ClientMetric*, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric>&) at d:\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289
      (inlined by) std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> >::vector(std::vector<prometheus::ClientMetric, std::allocator<prometheus::ClientMetric> > const&) at d:\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/stl_vector.h:463
      (inlined by) prometheus::MetricFamily::MetricFamily(prometheus::MetricFamily const&) at src/lib/prometheus/metric_family.h:11
  #7  0x400da826:0x3ffdba60 in prometheus::Family::Collect() const at src/lib/prometheus/family.h:252
  #8  0x400d35cd:0x3ffdbbb0 in prometheus::Registry::Collect() const at src/lib/prometheus/registry.h:74
  #9  0x400dc5cd:0x3ffdbc00 in initWebServer()::{lambda(AsyncWebServerRequest*)#2}::operator()(AsyncWebServerRequest*) const at src/main.cpp:187
  #10 0x400de6fd:0x3ffdc180 in std::_Function_handler<void (AsyncWebServerRequest*), initWebServer()::{lambda(AsyncWebServerRequest*)#2}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, AsyncWebServerRequest*&&) at d:\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_function.h:297
  #11 0x400f18af:0x3ffdc1a0 in std::function<void (AsyncWebServerRequest*)>::operator()(AsyncWebServerRequest*) const at d:\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_function.h:687
  #12 0x400f18ea:0x3ffdc1d0 in AsyncCallbackWebHandler::handleRequest(AsyncWebServerRequest*) at .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/WebHandlerImpl.h:132
  #13 0x400eef99:0x3ffdc220 in AsyncWebServerRequest::_parseLine() at .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/WebRequest.cpp:581 (discriminator 1)
  #14 0x400ef059:0x3ffdc270 in AsyncWebServerRequest::_onData(void*, unsigned int) at .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/WebRequest.cpp:123
  #15 0x400ef311:0x3ffdc2d0 in std::_Function_handler<void (void*, AsyncClient*, void*, unsigned int), AsyncWebServerRequest::AsyncWebServerRequest(AsyncWebServer*, AsyncClient*)::{lambda(void*, AsyncClient*, void*, unsigned int)#8}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, void*&&, AsyncClient*&&, std::_Any_data const&, unsigned int&&) at .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/WebRequest.cpp:76
      (inlined by) _M_invoke at d:\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_function.h:297
  #16 0x400ead27:0x3ffdc2f0 in std::function<void (void*, AsyncClient*, void*, unsigned int)>::operator()(void*, AsyncClient*, void*, unsigned int) const at d:\user\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_function.h:687
  #17 0x400ead76:0x3ffdc320 in AsyncClient::_recv(tcp_pcb*, pbuf*, signed char) at .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:915
  #18 0x400eadb9:0x3ffdc340 in AsyncClient::_s_recv(void*, tcp_pcb*, pbuf*, signed char) at .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:1191
  #19 0x400eaf01:0x3ffdc360 in _handle_async_event(lwip_event_packet_t*) at .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:159
  #20 0x400eaf86:0x3ffdc380 in _async_service_task(void*) at .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:194
```

It might be worth noting that some of this error is relating to https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer code, because Prometheus must scrape the metrics via an endpoint.

```cpp
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "metrics.h"
#include "utils.h"

AsyncWebServer httpServer(80);

void initWebServer() {
  httpServer.on("/metrics", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    request->client()->setRxTimeout(10);
    Serial.println("[httpServer] /metrics...");

    std::string bufStr (10000, 'x');
    std::stringstream bodyStream(bufStr);
    prometheus::TextSerializer::Serialize(bodyStream, metrics::Registry.Collect());
    const std::string bodyString = bodyStream.str();
    Serial.print("bodyString.length(): ");
    Serial.println(bodyString.length());
    const char *bodyChars = bodyString.c_str();
    //Serial.println(bodyChars);

    request->send_P(
        200,
        "text/plain",
        bodyChars
    );
  });
}

void setup() {
  initWebServer();
}
```

Comment: "mysterious limit of 8192 characters?" it does?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str  I don't see it

Comment: Apparently it does, which is why my debug printing never prints the full string - it's always limited to a maximum of 8192 characters.

Comment: what is limited to 8192? The value printed by `bodyString.length()` ? The number of characters on the screen from `Serial.println(bodyChars);` ? Both ?

Comment: `Serial.println(bodyString.length())` prints at most 8192, `Serial.println(bodyChars)` prints at most 8192 characters (including new lines).

Comment: This is nothing inherent to `stringstream`. Perhaps the arduino implementation has to specially defined limits.

Comment: Try constructing the `std::stringstream` providing a pre-sized larger string to use as its buffer.

Comment: Don't mess with the buffer. Given `std::string s`, you can insert string `s` into a stringstream at construction, like this: `std::stringstream sst(s);`, or afterwards, like this: `sst.clear(); sst.str(s);`.

Comment: @xaxxon Please note that that value is probably the default `BUFSIZE`, it's not limited to arduino (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184301/file-output-stops-after-outputting-8192-characters).

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the question with my attempt., but unfortunately it triggers an error

Comment: @tbxfreeware: That *is* replacing the buffer of the stringstream.

Comment: @aSemy: Best guess is you don't have enough heap.  In your first version the `vector<prometheus::ClientMetric>` gets the memory first and your `stringstream` fails to expand (but makes the best of the smaller buffer it already has).  Preallocating the buffer causes `prometheus::ClientMetric` to fail to allocate during a copy, and it doesn't deal with the shortage so nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to determine the reason for the 8192 limit, but I have implemented a workaround.

First, I updated [`text_serializer.h`](https://github.com/biaks/prometheus-cpp-lite/blob/8f252c36e55d8a82cae16df9eeed9ed64199643c/core/include/prometheus/text_serializer.h) to write the contents to a [Stream](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/), not a `std::stringstream`, because a File is a type of Stream.

For example, I changed the `WriteValue()` function from

```cpp
  static void WriteValue(std::ostream &out, const std::string &value) {
    for (auto c: value) {
      switch (c) {
        case '\n':
          out << '\\' << 'n';
          break;
        case '\\':
            out << '\\' << c;
            break;
        case '"':
          out << '\\' << c;
          break;
        default:
          out << c;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

to

```cpp
  static void WriteValue(Stream &out, const std::string &value) {
    for (auto c: value) {
      switch (c) {
        case '\n':
          out.print("\\n");
          break;
        case '\\':
        case '"':
          out.print("\\");
          out.print(c);
          break;
        default:
          out.print(c);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

This still had a limit on the size of the string (which was slightly less than 8192, which is strange, but I didn't investigate further).

I also created a separate task to collect the metrics and write them to a file, using LittleFS. Instead of writing to the same file that would be read by another task, which would risk concurrency issues if the file was read while it was being written, it writes to a temporary file and re-names the file.

```cpp
void collectMetricsTask(void *) {
  while (true) {
    File file = LittleFS.open("/metrics-tmp.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    if (!file) {
      Serial.println("There was an error opening metrics-tmp.txt for writing");
    } else {
      prometheus::TextSerializerStream::Serialize(file, metrics::Registry.Collect());
      file.close();
    }
    const auto renamed = LittleFS.rename("/metrics-tmp.txt", "/metrics.txt");
    if (!renamed) {
      Serial.println("failed to rename metrics-tmp.txt to metrics.txt");
    }
    delay(10000); // 10 seconds
    yield();
  }
}
```

The metrics can then be read in a separate task, and the full contents are available. No more 8192 limit!

For example, the metrics file can be read by ESPAsyncWebServer:

```cpp
void initWebServer() {
  httpServer.on("/metrics", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    Serial.println("[httpServer] /metrics...");
    request->send(LittleFS, "/metrics.txt", "text/plain");
  });
```